# Conflict between Vue Router & Laravel routes when add param to a route

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, laravel-routing

As you can see, I added `{locale?}` to the first route that I can use the localization features. but if I want to go to **url.com/en/vue-url** the Vue router doesn't show any page and it returns `Unexpected token '<'` error in the console.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['Localization']], function () {
    Route::get('/{locale?}', function(){
        return view('home');
    });
});

Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {
    return view('spa');
})->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

I searched a lot but didn't find any reason or solution to solve this issue.

Comment: Unexpected token '<' means its not returning json

Comment: so how can I fix it? @flakerimi

Comment: I dont know without code but part that vue gets data is not json its html, just check api calls